# Wordpress Multiple Navigation bars

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is more of a 'Is it possible question" I have a home page which has a full width header and a transparent Navbar, when you scroll this Navbar changes to white. On all my other pages I want this Navbar to start white and stay white as you scroll.

At the moment Im using jQuery to make the Navbar turn white which works fine of course. But does anyone know how I can achieve what I have described?

Any Answers/Suggestions appreciated and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Most WordPress themes take advantage of a function called [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) which outputs specific classes to the body tag. Implementation looks something like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This will put a unique class on the homepage of your website that won't be on any of the other pages so you could target that specifically in jQuery or use some kind of JQuery function like `hasClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

So I have done figured out a solution using php Ill explain below:

So I created a var and called it white. It has a empty string that I used and an if statement then I used the WordPress function `is_front_page`

```
<?php 
    $white = "";
    if( !is_front_page() ) {
        $white = 'scrolled';
    }
?>
```

Then in my Navbar class I added this:

```
<?php echo $white; ?>
```

Lastly My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('.navbar').toggleClass('scrolled', $(window).scrollTop() >= 50);
    });
});
```

This methord works perfectly!